# PHP variable scope manual "The global keyword"

Tags: php

According to the [PHP variable scope manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#example-113) in the "The global keyword" section we have the following piece of code:

```
<?php
    $a = 1;
    $b = 2;

    function Sum()
    {
        global $a, $b;

        $b = $a + $b;
    } 

    Sum();
    echo $b;
?>
```

> The above script will output 3.

but in my case is echo out 2.

I misunderstand something?

Comment: Can't reproduce it: http://3v4l.org/Xq3kU Maybe restart your server.

Comment: Is echo out 3 in .php file and 2 in .phtml file for any reason that I don't know. Could anybody explain why in a few words?

Comment: @FranMercaes 1. Did you restarted your server? 2. What php version do you have? 3. Is this your entire script? 4. What is the file extension? <-- Add all these things into your question (besides point 1) to specify your question more, so that other people can try to reproduce it

Comment: I don't believe all this is that relevant but here we go. Indeed I restarted the server Just because you say so not because I was sure that can help. @Rizier123 . My PHP version is: PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.9 (cli) (built: Apr 17 2015 11:44:57) and yes is my entire script inasmuch as I'm just reading the manual and playing around nothing else.

Comment: @FranMercaes PHP has been procedural in those days and today you can decide whether to continue writing procedural code or to switch to object oriented programming. That means there are some keywords like `global` which are not necessary anymore and I would not recommend to learn that old stuff. `global` always means global/static context which means no isolation of components which is bad practice for OOP programmers. But now to your problem: try to set your error_reporting to E_ALL. Maybe newer PHP versions have global marked deprecated or it's just a typo in your code?

Comment: I don't think is any typo. I copy/paste the code from the manual. My error_reporting is set to E_ALL in php.ini. I'm just curious why this happens I never used $GLOBAL or global because just like you said  " is bad practice for OOP programmers" but in PHP Certification Study Guide Book they keep talking about global statement. Maybe is failing because the .phtml file where I was trying is part of ZF2 View. I really don't know. Just speculating.

Comment: @FranMercaes **ZF2** Ah! You use a framework! See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29971231/3933332

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the Sum() function in order to modify the value of $b. Make sure you call it before you echo. If you encapsulated your $a and $b inside a function or class or namespace, it will not work like in that example.

Comment: As you can see in OP's code he calls `Sum()`. Also he doesn't have `$a` or `$b` in a namespace or something like this.