# Global not working in a function PHP 5.5.9 on Ubuntu server 14.04

Tags: php, function, global

My Global variables are not working inside a function 
example. If i do the following

```
$a=10;
function myfunction() {
global $a;
echo ($a+5);
}
myfunction();
```

it returns nothing
but it works this way around

```
function myfunction() {
//global $a;
$a=10;
echo ($a+5);
}
myfunction();
```

all code is on the same page

Here is the problem function and what i have to do to get it to work

```
function encryptAndEncode($strIn) {
//global $strEncryptionType
      //,$strEncryptionPassword;
$strEncryptionType="AES";
$strEncryptionPassword="MyPassword";
    //** AES encryption, CBC blocking with PKCS5 padding then HEX encoding - DEFAULT **

    //** use initialization vector (IV) set from $strEncryptionPassword
    $strIV = $strEncryptionPassword;

    //** add PKCS5 padding to the text to be encypted
    $strIn = addPKCS5Padding($strIn);

    //** perform encryption with PHP's MCRYPT module
    $strCrypt = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $strEncryptionPassword, $strIn, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $strIV);

    //** perform hex encoding and return
    return "@" . strtoupper(bin2hex($strCrypt));

}
```

Comment: Do you use any frameworks ?

Comment: Do you include this file into some other files or wrap it into other functions? (Otherwise I [can't reproduce your problem](http://3v4l.org/9ORJn) So you need to give us a minimal example to reproduce your problem)

Comment: No, as mentioned above all the script is on the same page with no includes. It is really stange as it is only this server it does it on.

Comment: They are my own servers hosting several sites with Apache, PHP 5.5.9

Comment: Just simply restart your server and try again, otherwise you have to provide us an example, with which we can reproduce your problem. + Is this the **full** and **real** code which you show us here?

Comment: No this is just an example, I am using mysagepay with AES and V3.0 protocol Using their mycrypt AES on one server with the global Encryption Type  and Password being called inside the encrypt function works fine....But on a different server I have to decalre the Encryption protocol and Password again. It is really strange. The above example is just a simple version of what is happening

Comment: ^^ Well, then add this information into your question.

Comment: I will edit and put the actual function with the example above

Comment: Edited the above so you can see :)

Comment: I don't see what the problem now is with the real code? What is your current output and what do you expect to get? Also do you get any errors ?

Comment: Can you  show us, where the variable is initialized. and how and where this function is called..

Comment: Figured it out and am posting the answer (My error which others might make :) )

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue :) Others may be having this problem. Though this is a separate page it is running inside wordpress and the code is direct on a page and not as a require or include.

To get around this I have to remove the vars that are set on the page and declare them in the the themes functions.php

It seems if you run globals inside anything to do with wordpress whether it is direct on the page or an include file, they all have to be pre declared in the themes function php. 
:)

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29970760/3933332 And also try the solution from the answer, would be interesting to see if it is the same.