# I keep getting this error "in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given"

Tags: php, arrays

I'm gettin this error "in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given" even though I have "$c = array();"

heres my code below:

```
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });

    get('pro', function(){

        $to_crawl = "http://bestspace.co";
        $c = array();

        function get_links($url)
        {
            global $c;
            $input = @file_get_contents($url);
            $regexp = '<a\s[^>]*href=(\"??)([^" >]*?)\\1[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>';
            preg_match_all("/$regexp/siU", $input, $matches);
            $base_url = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);

            $l = $matches[2];

            foreach($l as $link)
            {



                if (strpos($link, "#"))
                {
                    $link = substr($link, 0, strpos($link, "#"));
                }

                if (substr($link,0,1) == ".")
                {
                    $link = substr($link, 1);
                }

                if (substr($link, 0, 7) == "http://")
                {
                    $link = $link;
                }

                else if (substr($link, 0, 8) == "https://")
                {
                    $link = $link;
                }

                else if (substr($link, 0, 2) == "//")
                {
                    $link = substr($link, 2);
                }

                else if (substr($link, 0, 2) == "#")
                {
                    $link = $url;
                }

                else if (substr($link, 0, 7) == "mailto:")
                {
                    $link = "[". $link."]";
                }

                else
                {
                    if (substr($link, 0, 1) != "/")
                    {
                        $link = $base_url."/".$link;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        $link = $base_url.$link;
                    }
                }


                if (substr($link, 0, 7) != "http://" && substr($link, 0, 8) != "https://" && substr($link, 0, 1) != "[")
                {
                    if (substr($url, 0, 8) == "https://")
                    {
                        // prepend https
                        $link = "https://".$link;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // prepend http
                        $link = "http://".$link;
                    }
                }



                //echo $link."<br>";
                if (!in_array($link, $c))
                {
                    array_push($c, $link);
                }
            }

        }

        get_links($to_crawl);

        foreach ($c as $page)
        {
            echo $page."<br>";
        }
    });
```

the problem is comming from here

```
 if (!in_array($link, $c))
     {
          array_push($c, $link);
     }
```

It's complaining about $c, but it's global and I also have it as

$c = array();

any help as to why this is occurring will be appreciated.

Comment: Your array declaration is not in global scope.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29970760/3933332

Comment: I'm following the tutorial verbatim so to speak. And all you did was name my problem without providing guidance. The link you provided isn't the same as mine

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: @losee `$c = array();` -> `$GLOBALS["c"] = array();`

Comment: @John Current PHP version: 5.6.12-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1

Comment: @Rizier123 tried what you provided, it didn't work

Comment: @losee, you sure? Rizier's link looks like it should work. You instantiated the array and *then* you defined it in the global scope. You have to instantiate it *after* defining it in the global scope.

Comment: If I replace it as he states above I get "Undefined variable: c"

Comment: `$GLOBALS["c"] = array ();` instead of `global $c;`

Comment: why don't you let get_links($url) return an array and use it after that ?

Comment: @losee Works fine for me: https://3v4l.org/cRMjk

Comment: global variables are certainly not the best way to deal with this...

Answer (score 2):

This is where the problem really originates:

```
    get('pro', function(){

         $to_crawl = "http://bestspace.co";
         $c = array();

         function get_links($url)
         {
             global $c;
```

The `$c = array()` is inside the closure that you passed as second argument for the get()-function, and **that is not in the global namespace**, but in the closure namespace. **Using `global $c` wont work**, then.

To fix this, just pass on the $c in the get_links() function

```
    function get_links($url, array &$c)
    {
```

Comment: should'nt the signature contain &$c  ? Without reference the original array $c would not be changed

Comment: @shock_gone_wild Right are you! I didn't realize the array had to be changed. Thanks.

Comment: this did not work. now I get this error    Argument 2 passed to get_links() must be of the type array, none given, called in /home/vagrant/Code/wire/app/Http/routes.php on line 104 and defined

Comment: if you calll the function then it would be get_links($to_crawl, $c);

Comment: @losee Let met quote for you my answer "To fix this, just pass on the $c in the get_links() function"

Answer (score -1):

in your get_links() function, have you tried the "use()" clause?

```
function get_links() use($c) {
    print_r($c)
}
```

Comment: The `use` clause is only for anonymous functions, AKA closures. It doesn't work with a named function.

Comment: No access to try that, but I just learned that you cannot inject scope into a named function even inside and anonymous function. Thanks @IMSoP